# Why is my directive getting an "empty" bounding client rect for el[0]?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a directive that is trying to place an element that was appended to the body of the page below the element on which the directive is used.  My research would indicate that getting the actual top and left of the element that I want to display under, I can use `el[0].getBoundingClientRect()`, however, when I use that in the directive, I get a "blank" rect reference (all properties set to 0).  Just to make sure, I did `console.log(el[0])` in the directive, and then manually selected the same element in the console window to compare them and see if I could get the Bounding Rect in the console window, which I could.  Here are the relevant console lines:

**From the directive:**

```
console.log(el[0]);
-> <div tabindex=​"1" class=​"form-control border-radius ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" time-for=​"schedule.monday.startTime" id="div">​1:29 PM​</div>​
console.log(el[0].getBoundingClientRect());
-> ClientRect {height: 0, width: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0…}
```

**From the console:**

```
document.getElementById("div");
-> <div tabindex=​"1" class=​"form-control border-radius ng-binding ng-isolate-scope" time-for=​"schedule.monday.startTime" id=​"div">​1:29 PM​</div>​
document.getElementById("div").getBoundingClientRect();
-> ClientRect {height: 34, width: 90, left: 618, bottom: 347, right: 708…}
```

Is there a reason that I can't get a valid rectangle reference in the directive that is obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getBoundingClientRect` will return zero if the element or one of its ancestors is styled `display: none`.  You can use `visibility: hidden` to still hide it but get an appropriate size.

Also, if you have floated elements inside your element, the height might be zero.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#a').getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(document.querySelector('#b').getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(document.querySelector('#c').getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(document.querySelector('#d').getBoundingClientRect());
```

```html
see console

<div id="a" style="display: none;">hidden bits</div>
<div style="display: none;">
    <div id="b">hidden bits</div>
</div>
<div id="c" style="visibility: hidden;">hidden bits</div>
<div id="d" style="">
    <div style="float: left;">floated</div>
    <div style="float: left;">floated</div>
</div>
```